# iterate through 2D vector, cant dereference?

Tags: visual-c++, iterator, 2d-vector

I am trying to initialize two iterators two my 2D vector, one for the rows and one for the columns. I have done it this way:

```
vector<vector<int> > v;
    vector<vector<int> >::iterator r;
    vector<int>::iterator c;

    r = v.begin();
    c = r->begin();
```

and i get the following pop-up window, when i run the code:
Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression: can't dereference value initialized vector iterator.

There are som problem with this statement:

```
c = r->begin();
```

But cant see why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`v` is empty, so `r` doesn't point to a valid `vector<int>` instance (there is no instance to point to). You are essentially dereferencing `v.end()`, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.